# Remove / Delete similar duplicate keyword from URL htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, duplicates, keyword

I have this url:

```
http://www.domain.net/iphone-reparatur-bremen/iphone-6-**reparatur**
```

and want this:

```
http://www.domain.net/iphone-**reparatur**-bremen/iphone-6
```

I have many links (200+) like this.

How can I remove the last word "reparatur" from url?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)xn--domain-3ya.de
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.de [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^-/]+-([^/-]+)-[^/]+/.+?)-\2\b /$1 [NC,L,R=302]
#RewriteRule ^(iphone-([^/]+)-[^/]+/iphone-\d)-\2\b /$1 [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?.html=%1 [R,L]



#Für weiterleitung von/auf root
Redirect 301 /de/ http://www.domain.de/

#haupt-kategorien
Redirect 301 /handy http://www.domain.de
Redirect 301 /handy-reparatur http://www.domain.de
Redirect 301 /handy-reparatur-bremen http://www.domain.de
```

and there are many 301..
ignoremeignoremeignoremeignoremeignoremeignoremeignoreme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this back-reference based rule to find and remove duplicate parts in your rules. Place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^-/]+-([^/-]+)-[^/]+/.+?)-\2\b /$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

It is capturing value after initial `/iphone-` and grouping it in this sub-pattern `([^/]+)`. Later in the regex it is using back-reference `\2` to make sure same captured value is in the end as well.

`\b` is used for word boundary.

This will redirect:

```
/iphone-reparatur-bremen/iphone-6-reparatur => /iphone-reparatur-bremen/iphone-6
/iphone-foobar-something/iphone-6-foobar => /iphone-foobar-something/iphone-6
```

Comment: really thanks for quick reply! I tested it but it doesn't worked. I have different urls for example like `www.domain.net/samsung-reparatur-bremen/samsung-galaxy-s5-mini-reparatur`

Comment: no, it doesn't work.. it is possible that your rewrite rule crashes with other rules?

Comment: ok you need to place my suggested rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: it worked! :) I placed it ater RewriteEngine On
thank you very much!